# Anyone found a good way to transport kids with a Strida?

Tags: cargo, trailer, children

Are there any compatible trailers or such for a [Strida](http://www.strida.com/)?

The strida is a bike frame designed with single-side mounts for the wheels, and they are on the Right hand side.

There is no axle connection or chainstay on the left side of the bike where most trailers would expect to connect.

[image]
 Generic photo showing lefthand side of a Strida bike.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

Yes, I've found a way to attach a Thule Chariot Cross Lite 2

The trailer is intended to work with the hitching arm mounted on the **left** side of the bike, however there is a specular arm mount on the right side which is there for other attachment purposes (the single wheel for jogging), so I managed to attach the hitching arm on the right side where you have the rear wheel bolt.

I have to say it's not a shaky accommodation, it's very well connected and firm indeed.

I didn't notice too much effort on my strida, especially using the first and the second of the 3 gears ratio (I have a strida evo 3). –

The disk brakes are excellent also with this additional weight and I don't notice any fatigue on them in braking. The Thule chariot cross lite 2, as well as all other chariots, have this particular feature of the hitching arm mount for which this represented my only option to be coupled with the strida.

Obviously you can adapt also other trailers but this solution is equally safe as the original mounting option. If someone need some other details on this, please let me know.

Comment: When I was looking for solutions on which trailers suited my strida, I didn't find anything around and I've made this blind trial, fortunately I was a good one.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that one might possibly attach a lightweight trailer to that rack sort of deal on the back, or possibly to the seat stay.  Since the thing has such a short wheelbase with the rider's weight so far backwards, there would be a bit of a problem with the bike doing a wheelie, however.

Comment: Any particular models or brands?

Comment: I'd try to find a shop that carries several and take the bike there (assuming you have the bike already).

Comment: @spongefile - You might consider waiting to accept this as the answer; seeing that green checkmark can preclude others from answering a question. (Although I agree that a trailer is probably the way to go for this.)

Comment: @spongefile - write to `contact@strida.com` and get them to post an answer up here.